# Let $t_n$ denote the $n$th triangular number. For what values of $n$ does $t_n$ divide $t_1^2+t_2^2+ \cdots +t_n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $t_n$ denote the $n$th triangular number. For what values of $n$ does $t_n$ divide $t_1^2+t_2^2+ \cdots +t_n^2$.

The hint says that because $t_1^2+t_2^2+ \cdots +t_n^2 = t_n(3n^3 + 12n^2 + 13n + 2)/30$, it suffices to determine those $n$ satisfying $3n^3+12n^2+13n+2 \equiv 0$ (mod 2*3*5). However, I don't see how to get $t_1^2+t_2^2+ \cdots +t_n^2 = t_n(3n^3 + 12n^2 + 13n + 2)/30$ this equiation in the first place. Also, I'm trying to solve the congruence $3n^3+12n^2+13n+2 \equiv 0$ for each mod 2, 3, 5 respectively but I have been unable so far to find the $n$ that satisfies these congruences. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: note that (n+2)is a factor of cubic polynomial

Answer (score 2):

A direct proof of the summation is desirable and illuminating.  Recall $t_n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.  Then the goal is to evaluate $$T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n t_k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{4} k^2 (k+1)^2 = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n (k^4 + k^2) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n k^3.$$  We can recall that $$\begin{align*} S_2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 &= \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1), \\ S_3 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 &= \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2, \end{align*}$$ but the formula for $S_4$ is less well known.  We show how to derive it in two ways, and in turn, show how both methods can also be used to derive $S_2$ and $S_3$.

**Method 1.**

Consider the telescoping sum $$\begin{align*} (n+1)^5 - 1 &= \sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)^5 - k^5 = \sum_{k=1}^n (5k^4 + 10k^3 + 10k^2 + 5k + 1) \\ &= 5S_4 + 10S_3 + 10S_2 + 5S_1 + n.\end{align*}$$ Rearranging, we obtain $$\begin{align*} S_4 &= \frac{1}{5} \left( (n+1)((n+1)^4-1) - \frac{5n^2(n+1)^2}{2} - \frac{5n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3} - \frac{5n(n+1)}{2} \right) \\ &= \frac{n+1}{30}\left(6\left((n+1)^4 - 1\right) - 15n^2(n+1) - 10n(2n+1) - 15n  \right) \\ &= \frac{n(n+1)}{30} \left( 6n^3 +24n^2 +36n +24 - 15n^2 - 15n - 20n - 10 - 15 \right) \\ &= \frac{n(n+1)}{30}(6n^3 +9n^2 +n - 1) \\ &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2 + 3n - 1)}{30}. \end{align*}$$  From here, it is straightforward to compute $T_n$.  Note that in general considering the telescoping sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)^{m+1} - k^{m+1} = (n+1)^{m+1} - 1$$ while knowing $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_{m-1}$, permits us to find $S_m$, albeit rather tediously.  However, we could have proceeded more directly by observing from an intermediate step that $$T_n = \frac{S_4}{4} + \frac{S_3}{2} + \frac{S_2}{4} = \frac{(n+1)^5 - 1 - 5S_2 - 5S_1 - n}{20},$$ thus saving us the trouble of finding $S_4$ explicitly (or even needing to know $S_3$).

**Method 2.**

Estimate the sum as an integral.  Consider $$I_n = \frac{1}{4} \int_{x=0}^n x^2 (x+1)^2 \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \left[ \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{2} + \frac{x^5}{5} \right]_{x=0}^n = \frac{n^5}{20} + \frac{n^4}{8} + \frac{n^3}{12}.$$  Then $$\begin{align*} T_n - I_n &= \frac{1}{4} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n k^2(k+1)^2 - \int_{x=k-1}^k x^2 (x+1)^2 \, dx \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(2k^3 + k^2  - \tfrac{1}{30} \right) \\ &= \frac{S_3}{2} + \frac{S_2}{4} - \frac{n}{120} ,\end{align*}$$ and adding $I_n$ to both sides then gives the desired result.  This method was used directly on $T_n$ but we could have just as easily applied it to find $S_2$, $S_3$, or $S_4$.

Answer (score 1):

The equality
$$ t_{1}^{2}+t_{2}^{2}+\cdots+t_{n}^{2}=t_n(3n^3+12n^2+13n+2)/30$$
can be proved by the mathematical induction:

(1) $n=1$. This is obvious: $t_{1}^{2}=1=t_1(3+12+13+2)/30$.

(2) Assume that formula holds for $n$. Then
$$ t_{1}^{2}+t_{2}^{2}+\cdots+t_{n}^{2}+t_{n+1}^{2}=t_n(3n^3+12n^2+13n+2)/30+t_{n+1}^{2} = $$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\cdot \frac{3n^3+12n^2+13n+2}{30}+\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4}=$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(3n^4+27n^3+88n^2+122n+60)}{60}. $$
On the other hand
$$t_{n+1}\frac{3(n+1)^3+12(n+1)^2+13(n+1)+2}{30}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(3(n+1)^3+12(n+1)^2+13(n+1)+2)}{60}= $$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(3n^4+27n^3+88n^2+122n+60)}{60}. $$
Thus the formula holds for any $n\in {\mathbb N}$.

To see when $30\bigl|(3n^3+12n^2+13n+2)$ we note that $3n^3+12n^2+13n+2$ is an even integer
for any $n$. For divisibility with $3$ we consider three cases:

(i) $n\equiv 0\qquad (\mod 3) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 2\quad (\mod 3)$

(ii) $n\equiv 1\qquad (\mod 3) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 0\quad (\mod 3)$

(iii) $n\equiv 2\qquad (\mod 3) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 1\quad (\mod 3).$

For divisibility with $5$ we consider five cases:

(i) $n\equiv 0\qquad (\mod 5) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 2\quad (\mod 5)$

(ii) $n\equiv 1\qquad (\mod 5) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 0\quad (\mod 5)$

(iii) $n\equiv 2\qquad (\mod 5) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 0\quad (\mod 5)$

(iv) (i) $n\equiv 3\qquad (\mod 5) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 0\quad (\mod 5)$

(v) $n\equiv 4\qquad (\mod 5) \quad \Rightarrow\quad 3n^3+12n^2+13n+2\equiv 3\quad (\mod 5)$

We conclude that $n$ has to satisfty  $n\equiv 1\qquad (\mod 3)$ and  $n\equiv 1\, \text{or}\, 2 \,\text{or}\, 3\qquad (\mod 5) $. It follows that $n$ is of the form
$$ n=15m+r\quad \text{where} \quad m\in {\mathbb N}\cup \{ 0\}\quad \text{and}\quad r\in \{ 1, 7, 13\}. $$

I hope that there is no mistake in my calculations.